# How to control media player while playing a game with Logitech Keyboard?

Tags: logitech-keyboard, multimedia

Hey I've been trying to play games and play music in the background.

I have a multimedia player keyboard from Logitech.  When you press `<FN>` on the keyboard, you can press buttons `<F1>` to `<F10>` for the second function.  If I press `<FN> <F5>` it opens Winamp, which is cool, but the other buttons like "Play" etc. don't work, only in Windows Media Player.

This is fine, but can I somehow let the keys work in the background while playing a game?
It's cumbersome to press `<ALT> <TAB>` to go to the player and change the song.

Is there a solution so that I can play games and use the keyboard to skip music?

Answer (score 0):

The [Logitech Multimedia Keyboard Plugin for Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/logitech-multimedia-keyboard-plugin/78516) should sort you out.

[image]

It's a bit old (in Internet years it's prehistoric) but hopefully it still works - there are positive reviews within the last year at least.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want. First, which Logitech keyboard do you have? Some of them are programmable such as the G15 and G11 — which allow you to assign functions, macros, or hot-keys for whatever purpose you might need:

> http://www.logitech.com/en-us/434/285?section=downloads&bit=&osid=-1&file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.logitech.com%2Fpub%2Fgaming%2Fkeyboards%2FGamePanel3.06.128-Multi.dmg

If your keyboard isn't one of the programmable models, then you can also run a background application or script to control your music, volume, etc. Depending on what platform you're running and extent of your music control needs there are many options.

Answer (score 0):

A common issue with Logitech keyboards is the "gaming mode" switch. Often the "Gaming Mode" switch is a toggle on the top left of the keyboard. With it enabled, it deactivates or reassigns multiple keys, including the Windows keys and often including multimedia keys and function keys. Check to be sure you are not in "gaming mode" on your keyboard!